# Should I answer a simpler version of the question?

Tags: discussion

For example:

1) Someone asks how to get outputs X, Y, and Z labeled and formatted in a specific way and someone provides an answer.

2) Later, I search on how to get X, Y, and Z out, but with less stringent labeling and formatting needs and this question is the top/only result. The accepted answer is far more complicated than I need.

3) On my own, I find a simpler answer that works for me.

My inclination was to add an answer that acknowledged that this didn't meet the original poster's needs but offered my simpler problem's solution in case it would help others. However, this prompted quite the debate among moderators, causing my answer to be locked, deleted, and eventually restored but with my acknowledgment edited out.

Was my attempt to help others in my situation inappropriate?

Comment: The major flaw is not that it doesn't answer the question, it doesn't describe the "works for me" constraints.  There is a logical explanation for that, you just don't know for a fact that it always works for you.  That's the nice thing about answering SO questions, it forces you to write better specs and better code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be posting answers to questions that they actually answer.  If you want to post an answer to a similar, but different, question than one you've found, then post that answer to a similar, but different, question, that your answer actually answers.  If such a question doesn't exist, make it yourself, if you feel it would be useful to others.

Comment: This seems like the most useful. Write your own question, answer it, then mention it in the comments of the original questoin.

Comment: only worry then is the "this is  dup of" just because the original covered it, in a more complex way due to the additional stuff

Comment: @BugFinder If the existing answers to the existing question already cover everything you want to post in your answer then there's no reason to do *anything*.  There's no reason to post your answer at all, either to a new question, or the existing one.  There's only ever a point if you have something original (and useful) to add.

Comment: @SteveBennett I probably would have, but my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 8):

> My inclination was to add an answer that acknowledged that this didn't meet the original poster's needs but offered my simpler problem's solution in case it would help others.

***How*** does it help others, though?

In the context [of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/1079354), the OP is talking about representing a table (effectively, a matrix with row and column headers) from NumPy.  They want to pretty-print this.

Your answer is effectively ignoring the requirements:

- The output would incorporate the NumPy array.
- The output incorporates a list (so as to be useful to others, it can be a list of any length).

I don't *think* there's much of an issue if you wanted to answer a more generalized version of the question (e.g. if you wanted to break the main question down into something smaller yet repeatable for larger data sets), but you actually **have to answer the question as posed**.  Your answer doesn't read like it's accomplished that, so I can see why there's contention around it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What's ironic is that I also wanted to format a NumPy array into columns with headers, but I just didn't care about the row labels, which is probably why I found the OP's question. But when I wrote my answer I may have over-simplified/hand-waved-too-much.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying regarding not incorporating the NumPy array. The answer I gave does take in a multidimensional array and output it tabulated columns. I do see how I could have incorporated the list into my answer and will edit it to be more relavent to the OP's question.

Comment: Perhaps if your alternative answer weren't completely trivial (it's literally just "use tabs") it would hold some value on its own despite its slight tangential nature with respect to the question. I can see from its latest revision that you've already discovered how fleshing it out beyond triviality has it arriving at nothing more than a clone of the existing answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree that my first answer was trivial (although, as a noob, I didn't think of it until after I searched for the answer) and attempting to make it more robust caused it to be redundant. But neither of those were the reason given for deleting it, which was NAA, which prompted this question. So, while you are not saying anything wrong, you aren't answering my question (but, this is a comment, not a proposed answer, so I guess you don't get flagged? ;)  )

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how closely related the question you're answering is to the original question. If it's a minor variant, it's useful to add it as an additional answer; that way your answer benefits from the context of the original question and comments and the other answers. This happens often, for example, if an answer differs slightly based on software version or platform. It can also happen if a minor change to the question's scope leads to a simplification.

However, if the change to the question being answered is substantial, then it's better to post a separate question and answer it, and then add a comment to the original question linking to the new question.